# Polymorphic has_many :through NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

So I started to setup a has_many :through polymorphic association in my app. The models look like the following:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections, through: :collectionitems
  has_many :collectionitems, through: :collectable
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections, through: :collectionitems
  has_many :collectionitems, through: :collectable
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Album"
  has_many :songs, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Song"
  has_many :collectionitems
end

class Collectionitem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :collectable, polymorphic: true
end
```

This allows me to do the following calls:

`Collection.first.songs` => returns an array of songs for the first collection
`Collection.first.albums` => returns an array of albums for the first collection
`Collectionitem.first.collection` => returns the collection this Collectionitem belongs to
`Collectionitem.first.collectable` => returns the record this Collectionitem belongs to (song or album)

My problem comes when I try to find all the collections a specific album or song belongs to.

both `Song.first.collections` and `Album.first.collections` return the following error when called in rails console.

```
Song.first.collections
Song Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" ORDER BY "songs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `block in source_reflection'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `collect'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `source_reflection'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:579:in `derive_class_name'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:133:in `class_name'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:178:in `klass'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `block in source_reflection'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `collect'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `source_reflection'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:557:in `check_validity!'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `new'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `association'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `collections'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Can someone tell me what i've gotten wrong here. Its as if it doesn't see the songs relationship to the collection? I just don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: I think `through: :collectable` should be `as: :collectable`.

Comment: That worked @Damien! Thanks so much. Can I ask how you knew that? Is it documented somewhere, a rails 4 change?

Comment: Great! Yes, it's documented in the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations. Even though you might have most things covered, it is definitely worth running through the guides a couple of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @damien pointed out in a comment I needed to change:

```
has_many :collectionitems, through: :collectable
```

to:

```
has_many :collectionitems, as: :collectable
```

Once this was in place everythign worked as expected.

Thanks again @damien!

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but i'm not seeing where :collectable is mentioned as a class in your question.

Comment: :collectable is not a class it's the polymorphic assignment.